# Why cant I use the Windows Name space in WPF app but I can use it in a Universal app

Tags: c#, wpf

why am I able to use the Windows Namespace in windows universal application

For example
using Windows.Networking.Sockets;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;

But I cant use it in WPF?

I get red lines under Networking and Storage saying that the reference does not exist.

One fix I googled said to add the PresentationFramework as a reference.  Only problem is, I see PresentationFramework in the reference folder.

Thank you

Comment: Does the library exist as a reference? You might have to add them as a reference in your project.

Comment: What framework exactly are you targetting? Check in properties of project.

Comment: The .Net Framework 4.5.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .NET framework base class library is in a bit of a mess as there are different implementations, all from Microsoft, all with their own differences (historically there was the "Full Fat" Framework, the Client-Profile Framework, the Compact Framework and the Micro Framework for embedded devices, XNA for Xbox 360 and then Silverlight had its own version too).

Windows 8 added the Metro/Modern/"Store App" platform which is its own version of .NET with a slightly different, Twilight Zone-different, base class library known as the "Windows Runtime". This library which provides many of the types previously seen in the `System` namespace now under the `Windows` namespace. Windows 10 renamed the platform to "Universal Apps".

For more information see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/br230302.aspx. Frustratingly, Microsoft recommends:

> Typically, you do not simply convert an existing .NET Framework app to a Windows 8.x Store app; you redesign the .NET Framework app for the new user experience

For the user-interface layer, that sounds reasonable (as the Universal Platform has its own UX framework based on XAML, which is similar, but not identical, to WPF) - however the platform also requires you to modify *all* library code written against .NET to use the `Windows` namespace for IO, which places a significant burden on the developer - especially if they're using a third-party library they don't have source-code access to.

Comment: So how do I use the Windows.Networking.StreamSocket library in WPF?

Comment: @user3363744 You don't. You need to switch to `System.Net.Socket` or `System.Net.TcpClient`. If you're writing code for multiple platforms you'll need to abstract it away.